# How to verify a users facebook id when making ajax posts to php in facebook app

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I am looking for a way to verify a users facebook id when posting user specific data using ajax.

I want to be able to verify that a facebook user id is correct when posting data using ajax.

The problem being, that if I post the facebook id as part of my ajax data, it can be edited in the javascript.  I could make a graph call on the server side, but these are really slow, so I want to keep graph calls to a minimum. Preferably only calling it at the beginning.

Can any suggest an efficient/secure method?

Comment: Downvoted, as this is a dup of your last one. I've voted to close that one rather than this, as this has much more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end my solution was to grab the users facebook id via the php sdk and creating a hash of it by adding a salt and encoding it with md5.  When posting the form I include both the facebook id and the hash. I can then use the same salt value to double check that the facebook idea is correct before using it. This seems to provide enough security for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to avoid doing graph calls, but you can make a call client side as well and call the Facebook API:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  // Check that response.id matches the submitting user id
});
```

This will allow you to check against the logged in user's Facebook id. There's no way you can really modify anything in the javascript to 'fake' being a different logged in Facebook user.

Otherwise, I'm not sure how else you can verify the id unless you have a whole login system yourself, where by you can match session data to saved user data on the database on the server side.

Comment: Surly this is no more secure as I can inject a response?

Comment: That's true. You can change the Facebook id within the javascript, but I'm not sure what that would accomplish? I guess it depends on the action that you're doing. The access token granted by Facebook should prevent the code from acting as a different person if you were to try and set a different id. Maybe some more details on what it is you're doing when interacting with Facebook and what kind of scenarios you are trying to prevent?